# How to call static method provided by protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, static, protocols

How to access to `static` protocol method within a instance

I have a list of `Contact`, the contact can be a `FamilyContact` that inherit from `Contact` and the `GroupStatus protocol`

I want to call the static method from `GroupStatus` but in vain...

Here is my code

```
protocol GroupStatus {
    static func isPrivate() -> Bool // static method that indicates the status
}

protocol IsBusy {
    func wizzIt()
}

class AdresseBook {

    private var contacts = [Contact]()

    func addOne(c: Contact) {
        contacts.append(c)
    }

    func listNonPrivated() -> [Contact]? {

        var nonPrivateContact = [Contact]()

        for contact in contacts {
            // here is I should call the static method provided by the protocol
            if self is GroupStatus {
                let isPrivate = contact.dynamicType.isPrivate()
                if !isPrivate {
                    nonPrivateContact.append(contact)
                }
            }
            nonPrivateContact.append(contact)
        }

        return nonPrivateContact
    }
}

class Contact : Printable {

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func wizz() -> Bool {
        if let obj = self as? IsBusy {
            obj.wizzIt()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.name
    }
}

class FamilyContact: Contact, GroupStatus {

    static func isPrivate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

I can't compile `Contact.Type does not have a member named 'isPrivate'`

How can I call it ? It works if I delete the `static` keyword, but I think is more logical to define it static.

**If I replace**

```
let isPrivate = contact.dynamicType.isPrivate()
```

**by**

```
let isPrivate = FamilyContact.isPrivate()
```

It works, but I can have more than 1 subclasses

**If I remove the `static` keywork I can do it by this way :**

```
if let c = contact as? GroupStatus {
    if !c.isPrivate() {
        nonPrivateContact.append(contact)
    }
}
```

*But I want to keep the `static` keyword*

Comment: What is your actual problem? What are the results you expect and what are the results you currently have?

Comment: I added the error. I can't compile.

Comment: I would like to call `contact.isPrivate()` whatever the contact subclass is it

Comment: This might be related: https://openradar.appspot.com/20119848 *"Swift 1.1 and 1.2 won't let the programmer call a class method defined in a protocol."*

Comment: @MartinR yes, I think is related !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a bug or a non-supported feature. I would expect that
the following works:

```
if let gsType = contact.dynamicType as? GroupStatus.Type {
    if gsType.isPrivate() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, it does not compile:

```
error: accessing members of protocol type value 'GroupStatus.Type' is unimplemented
```

It *does* compile with `FamilyContact.Type` instead of `GroupStatus.Type`. A similar problem is reported here:

- [Swift 1.1 and 1.2: accessing members of protocol type value XXX.Type' is unimplemented](https://openradar.appspot.com/20119848)

Making `isPrivate()` an instance method instead of a class method is
the only workaround that I currently can think of, maybe someone comes
with a better solution ...

**Update for Swift 2 / Xcode 7:** As @Tankista noted below, this has
been fixed. The above code compiles and works as expected in Xcode 7 beta 3.

Comment: In swift 2.0 remove `.dynamicType` and it should work

Comment: @Tankista: The above code compiles and works in Swift 2. Removing `.dynamicType` caused a syntax error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
type(of: contact).isPrivate()
```

This should work in recent Swift.